# MVC select item in table send to controller method id and selected item

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I've been working on some code so that when an item is selected in a dropdown it is sent to a method on the controller. I something like:

```
@foreach (var invoiceLine in Model.InvoiceLines) {
                        <tr><td>
                        <span>Administrator:</span>
                        @Html.DropDownList("dropDownList", new[]
        { 
            new SelectListItem { Text="", Value="0" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "First", Value = "1" }, 
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Second", Value = "2" } 
        })
```

Combined with the `jQuery`:

```
$(function () {
        $("#dropDownList").change(function () {
            $("#dropDownList option:selected").each(function () {
                $.getJSON("/Home/Owner/" + $(this)[0].value, null, function (data) {
                    doSomething();
                });
            });
        });
```

Anyway as well as sending the selected item index I also want to send the `id` of each `invoiceLine` ie. `invoiceLine.id`.

Can someone please tell me how to do this?

Also I've realised I have a problem in my current code that the `jQuery` will only find the first `dropDown` named `dropDownList` even though there will be many.

Any way round this?

Am I going about this the right way?

Is there an entirely better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you adding data-attributes to your

```
@Html.DropDownList("dropDownList", new[]
    { 
        new SelectListItem { Text="", Value="0" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "First", Value = "1" }, 
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Second", Value = "2" } 
    }, new{data-id=@invoiceLine.id })
```

Later you will be able to get this value in your JQuery function as

```
$("select here your dropdown list").attr("data-id")
```

By the way, IDs are used to identify the *only* element, if you want to mark many elements (like in your case) use classes.

Answer (score 0):

Sending back the values immediately opens you to additional security attacks if you are doing anything with them.

In most cases you only want to return the value they selected (and even then you need to verify that it's a legitimate value based on what you sent them originally.)

Comment: How is it a security concern?

Comment: Any data from the browser is suspect at all times as it is EASILY replaceable.  Any time you are accepting data from the user the first thing you want to ask is.. what could someone do with this data that would hurt me?  Assuming you're using something to protect yourself from SQL injection attacks the answer may occasionally be nothing.. but even then it's best to take as little from the user as you need.